# Can we use sikuli for automation of http pop up?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, sikuli

I am using selenium for automation of web application . But i am getting http login (asking for username and password) pop ups on some web pages during automation. For that , i am using sikuli to automate those pop ups. I am using following code for it:

```
   private void loginWithSikuliInFirefox(){
       try{
       Screen screen=new Screen();
       Pattern  image1=new Pattern("Pictures/Uname.png");
       Pattern  image2=new Pattern("Pictures/Passwrd.png");
       Pattern  image3=new Pattern("Pictures/Ok1.png");

    screen.wait(image1,10);
    screen.type(image1,userName);
    screen.type(image2,password);
    screen.click(image3);
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("There is no alert");
       }
   }

   private void loginWithSikuliInChrome(){
       try{
       Screen screen=new Screen();
       Pattern  image1=new Pattern("Pictures/Username.png");
       Pattern  image2=new Pattern("Pictures/Password.png");
       Pattern  image3=new Pattern("Pictures/Login.png");

    screen.wait(image1,10);
    screen.type(image1,userName);
    screen.type(image2,password);
    screen.click(image3);
       }
       catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println("There is no alert");
       }
   }
```

I make two different function so that it can work in Firefox and Chrome. These are working perfectly.

So, using sikuli is better option  or should i use something else? I tried switch to alert but that is not working in chrome. Please suggest something other than switch to alert if sikuli is not a better option for it .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing direct URL that has htaccess/http popup then you can go with `http://username:password@www.yoursiteurl` pattern. It will bypass the login popup. This way execution will be faster than Sikuli implementation. Also you will have to add Sikuli execution files, Jars etc in your project folder.

Also you can use AutiIt to handle htaccess popup but it will work with Windows environment only. Sikuli will work with Win/Linux/Mac all. But you will have to capture different images for different OS/Browser combination. i.e. Code you have written for **Win Chrome** may not work with **Mac Chrome**.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I am using mac system. So i can't use AutoIT. And if i am using sikuli, then i need to make two different function and need to put browser on the front. I used url=http://username:password@www.yoursiteurl pattern but after using it or using driver.get(url) there are so many pop ups that i need to automate. please suggest something else if you have any other suggestion.

Comment: These Popups are windows popups or web based ones ? Web based ones can be handled via `Alert` or `switchwindow`. Else sikuli is better to use unless images of those popup are not getting changed.